# Zotero export update crashed biber

Tags: biblatex, biber, texmaker, zotero

Until I re-exported my library from Zotero, everything worked fine. Now with new references, something happened and I don't understand where the problem is. Nothing execpt for the `reference.bib` file has changed. I copy pasted all references from the original version of the `referece.bib` file to check whether it is some format that is changed but it also doesn't take that one. Running it in my console gives me the same output as running it in texmaker and as in the `Main.bbl` file:

```
Process started

INFO - This is Biber 2.14
INFO - Logfile is 'Main.blg'
INFO - Reading 'Main.bcf'
INFO - Found 14 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Globbing data source 'references.bib'
INFO - Globbed data source 'references.bib' to references.bib
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'references.bib' for section 0 
INFO - LaTeX decoding ... INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'references.bib'

Process exited with error(s)
```

My `Main.tex` file is (in short, I don't exactly know what might be important)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, left=20mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, right=20mm, headheight=15pt}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=nature]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}

\maketitle

\chapter{Summary}
\input{Chapters/Summary.tex}

\begin{spacing}{1}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{spacing}

\end{document}
```

I use texmaker with Biber. The only intersting warning I can extract is

```
Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex) Main
(biblatex) and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

Does anybody know what is going on here, how I could find out what the problem is or maybe even how to fix it?

Thank you so much!

Comment: when the biber log stops in the middle it normally indicates that the cache got corrupted.  run `biber --cache`  in a terminal and delete the file it reports. Then try again (it can then take longer as the cache must be unpacked anew)

Comment: Thank you! It seems to create a directory - I am supposed to delete that one? Sorry...

Comment: it doesn't create anything, it only reports the location of the cache.

Comment: That worked! Wow, thank you so much!